# How can I export/download the infopath form template (xsn file)?

Tags: infopath, forms-services, xsn

I am using SP2010. By checking the CA /_admin/ManageFormTemplates.aspx (CA -> InfoPath forms service > manage form template), I can find a list of xsn files that upload by our ex-developers.

Can I export/download the xsn file in order to import to another farm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know which site collection the form has been published to, you can download the form from the site collection. Go to the site collection "All Site Content > Form Templates" or `http://YourSite/YourPath/YourSiteCollection/FormServerTemplates/Forms/All%20Forms.aspx`to see all administrator-approved form templates published to the site collection.

Hover over the desired form, bring up the edit drop-down and use "Send to > Download a copy". That will download the form template, or .xsn, which you can design with InfoPath Designer or do whatever else you please.

Comment: However, the code behind had been compiled into dll file so I cannot get the source code from this XSN, right?

Comment: Also for the FormServerTemplates library, by default version history is not enabled. Can I enable it to keep track of all version of form templates?

Comment: No, you can't decompile DLLs and you can't access previous versions. Your question was about downloading the xsn so you could re-use it on a different farm. Your comments are about source code management, which is a different issue altogether.

Answer (score 2):

InfoPath XSN files are located and named in different ways depending on whether they are published in a form library, a list, or a content type.

SharePoint Library
When an InfoPath form is published to a SharePoint Library, the XSN file is located here:
.../LibraryName/forms/template.xsn

SharePoint List
When an InfoPath form is published to a SharePoint List, the XSN file is located here:
.../ListName/item/template.xsn

Content Type
When an InfoPath form is published as a Content Type, the XSN file is located here:
.../LibraryName/FormName.xsn

Note: Content type is the only location you are required to know in order to upload forms from SharePoint to the Formotus service. For libraries and lists you can simply copy the URL from your browser into the Formotus location field, and the service will find the XSN file

Answer (score 0):

Go to the online site and follow these steps:

Configuration -> Site configuration -> Site libraries and lists (select the one to be reviewed) -> Advanced configuration -> Edit template

This should request to open the form in Microsoft InfoPath.